# Can Python pickle lambda functions?

Tags: python, python-2.7, lambda, pickle

I have read in a number of threads that Python `pickle`/`cPickle` cannot pickle lambda functions. However the following code works, using Python 2.7.6:

```
import cPickle as pickle

if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = pickle.dumps(lambda x, y: x+y)
    f = pickle.loads(s)
    assert f(3,4) == 7
```

So what is going on? Or, rather, what is the limit of pickling lambdas?

[EDIT]
I think i know why this code runs. I forgot (sorry!) i am running stackless python, which has a form of micro-threads called tasklets executing a function. These tasklets can be halted, pickled, unpickled and continued, so i guess (asked on the stackless mailing list) that it also provides a way to pickle function bodies.

Comment: Could not replicate - in 2.7.6 (on OS X 10.9.4) I get `TypeError: can't pickle function objects`.

Comment: try pickle.loads from an other script; I think you pickle the reference to lambda wich, in the same scope, is preserved in memory and called.

Comment: Just to know, which version of cPickle are you using?

Comment: @Lars: `stackless` does exactly what `dill` does, in general… the major difference is that `stackless` replaces the call stack in C, while `dill` tries to register serialization functions using `ctypes` to work at the C layer as possible. `Stackless` can serialize all objects.

Comment: `cloudpickle` is the way: https://github.com/cloudpipe/cloudpickle

Answer (score 95):

Yes, python can pickle lambda functions… but only if you have something that uses `copy_reg` to register **how** to pickle lambda functions -- the package `dill` loads the `copy_reg` you need into the pickle registry for you, when you `import dill`.

```
Python 2.7.8 (default, Jul 13 2014, 02:29:54) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.1 ((tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66))] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
>>> import dill  # the code below will fail without this line
>>> 
>>> import pickle
>>> s = pickle.dumps(lambda x, y: x+y)
>>> f = pickle.loads(s)
>>> assert f(3,4) == 7
>>> f
<function <lambda> at 0x10aebdaa0>
```

get dill here: https://github.com/uqfoundation

Comment: I've tried on python3

     In [1]: import dill
     In [2]: import pickle
    In [3]: pickle.dumps(lambda x: (x+1, x+2))
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    PicklingError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-3-924e2f4cc7e0> in <module>()
    ----> 1 pickle.dumps(lambda x: (x+1, x+2))

    PicklingError: Can't pickle <function <lambda> at 0x7f08ee40ca60>: attribute lookup <lambda> on __main__ failed.

It only works if you import dill as pickle

Comment: @Ramast: you are correct -- in python3, you currently have to `import dill as pickle`.  In python2, what I have above works either way you do it.

Comment: @CharlieParker: Can you elaborate? The above should work for most "arbitrary" functions.

Comment: The answer is incorrect for Python 3.6 as it is - use `dill.dumps()` and `dill.loads()` instead.

Comment: @PavelVlasov: your comment is a duplicate of the initial comment on the answer.

Comment: @MikeMcKerns can you please expand on the differences between Py3 and Py2 version of `dill` ? Is `dill` not able to hijack the `pickle` module anymore? I was hoping that importing `dill` before `rq` (which internally uses `pickle`), I can make `rq` work with lambdas

Comment: @CiprianTomoiagă: The primary difference is that in python 2, there was `pickle` (python) and `cPickle` (C) -- and in python 3, it's now `pickle` (python) and `_pickle` (C)... however, `pickle.dump` (and `dumps`) uses `_pickle` (i.e. C)... and `dill` can currently only inject new methods into the python pickle registry. So, just importing `dill` doesn't work like it does in python 2.  Note that there is `pickle._dump` (and `_dumps`), which does use the python registry... so that works as in python 2.  Unfortunately most packages don't fall back to `_dump`, when `dump` fails.

Comment: @MikeMcKerns does it work if the code that has arbitrary pytorch (and data science) code? I am trying to pickle a pytorch neural net work pointer to lambda functions.

Comment: like in this case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61510810/how-does-one-pickle-arbitrary-pytorch-models-that-use-lambda-functions

Comment: it should.  I answered your question directly at the above link

Answer (score 49):

**Python can pickle lambdas.** We will cover Python 2 and 3 separately as implementation of pickle are different in different Python versions.

- **Python 3.6**

In Python 3, there is no module named `cPickle`. We have `pickle` instead which also doesn't support pickling of `lambda` functions by default. Let's see it's dispatch table:

```
>> import pickle
>> pickle.Pickler.dispatch_table
<member 'dispatch_table' of '_pickle.Pickler' objects>
```

Wait. I tried looking up **dispatch_table** of `pickle` not `_pickle`. `_pickle` is the alternative and faster C implementation of pickle. But we haven't imported it yet! This C implementation is imported automatically, if it is available, at the end of pure Python `pickle` module.

```
# Use the faster _pickle if possible
try:
    from _pickle import (
        PickleError,
        PicklingError,
        UnpicklingError,
        Pickler,
        Unpickler,
        dump,
        dumps,
        load,
        loads
    )
except ImportError:
    Pickler, Unpickler = _Pickler, _Unpickler
    dump, dumps, load, loads = _dump, _dumps, _load, _loads
```

We are still left with the question of pickling lambdas in Python 3. The answer is you **CAN'T** with the native `pickle` or `_pickle`. You will need to import `dill` or [cloudpickle](https://github.com/cloudpipe/cloudpickle) and use that instead of the native pickle module.

```
>> import dill
>> dill.loads(dill.dumps(lambda x:x))
<function __main__.<lambda>>
```

- **Python 2.7**

`pickle` uses **pickle registry** which is nothing but a mapping from `type` to the function to use for serializing (pickling) objects of that type.
You can see **pickle registry** as:

```
>> pickle.Pickler.dispatch

{bool: <function pickle.save_bool>,
 instance: <function pickle.save_inst>,
 classobj: <function pickle.save_global>,
 float: <function pickle.save_float>,
 function: <function pickle.save_global>,
 int: <function pickle.save_int>,
 list: <function pickle.save_list>,
 long: <function pickle.save_long>,
 dict: <function pickle.save_dict>,
 builtin_function_or_method: <function pickle.save_global>,
 NoneType: <function pickle.save_none>,
 str: <function pickle.save_string>,
 tuple: <function pickle.save_tuple>,
 type: <function pickle.save_global>,
 unicode: <function pickle.save_unicode>}
```

To pickle custom types, Python provides `copy_reg` module to register our functions. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copyreg.html). By default, `copy_reg`module supports pickling of the following additional types:

```
>> import copy_reg
>> copy_reg.dispatch_table

{code: <function ipykernel.codeutil.reduce_code>,
 complex: <function copy_reg.pickle_complex>,
 _sre.SRE_Pattern: <function re._pickle>,
 posix.statvfs_result: <function os._pickle_statvfs_result>,
 posix.stat_result: <function os._pickle_stat_result>}
```

Now, type of `lambda` functions is `types.FunctionType`. However, the builtin function for this type `function: <function pickle.save_global>` is not able to serialize lambda functions. Therefore, all third party libraries like `dill`, `cloudpickle`, etc override the inbuilt method to serialize lambda functions with some additional logic. Let's import `dill` and see what it does.

```
>> import dill
>> pickle.Pickler.dispatch

{_pyio.BufferedReader: <function dill.dill.save_file>,
 _pyio.TextIOWrapper: <function dill.dill.save_file>,
 _pyio.BufferedWriter: <function dill.dill.save_file>,
 _pyio.BufferedRandom: <function dill.dill.save_file>,
 functools.partial: <function dill.dill.save_functor>,
 operator.attrgetter: <function dill.dill.save_attrgetter>,
 operator.itemgetter: <function dill.dill.save_itemgetter>,
 cStringIO.StringI: <function dill.dill.save_stringi>,
 cStringIO.StringO: <function dill.dill.save_stringo>,
 bool: <function pickle.save_bool>,
 cell: <function dill.dill.save_cell>,
 instancemethod: <function dill.dill.save_instancemethod0>,
 instance: <function pickle.save_inst>,
 classobj: <function dill.dill.save_classobj>,
 code: <function dill.dill.save_code>,
 property: <function dill.dill.save_property>,
 method-wrapper: <function dill.dill.save_instancemethod>,
 dictproxy: <function dill.dill.save_dictproxy>,
 wrapper_descriptor: <function dill.dill.save_wrapper_descriptor>,
 getset_descriptor: <function dill.dill.save_wrapper_descriptor>,
 member_descriptor: <function dill.dill.save_wrapper_descriptor>,
 method_descriptor: <function dill.dill.save_wrapper_descriptor>,
 file: <function dill.dill.save_file>,
 float: <function pickle.save_float>,
 staticmethod: <function dill.dill.save_classmethod>,
 classmethod: <function dill.dill.save_classmethod>,
 function: <function dill.dill.save_function>,
 int: <function pickle.save_int>,
 list: <function pickle.save_list>,
 long: <function pickle.save_long>,
 dict: <function dill.dill.save_module_dict>,
 builtin_function_or_method: <function dill.dill.save_builtin_method>,
 module: <function dill.dill.save_module>,
 NotImplementedType: <function dill.dill.save_singleton>,
 NoneType: <function pickle.save_none>,
 xrange: <function dill.dill.save_singleton>,
 slice: <function dill.dill.save_slice>,
 ellipsis: <function dill.dill.save_singleton>,
 str: <function pickle.save_string>,
 tuple: <function pickle.save_tuple>,
 super: <function dill.dill.save_functor>,
 type: <function dill.dill.save_type>,
 weakcallableproxy: <function dill.dill.save_weakproxy>,
 weakproxy: <function dill.dill.save_weakproxy>,
 weakref: <function dill.dill.save_weakref>,
 unicode: <function pickle.save_unicode>,
 thread.lock: <function dill.dill.save_lock>}
```

Now, let's try to pickle lambda function.

```
>> pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(lambda x:x))
<function __main__.<lambda>>
```

It WORKS!!

In Python 2 we have two versions of `pickle` -

```
import pickle # pure Python version
pickle.__file__ # <install directory>/python-2.7/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py

import cPickle # C extension
cPickle.__file__ # <install directory>/python-2.7/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/cPickle.so
```

Now, let's try to pickle lambda with C implementation `cPickle`.

```
>> import cPickle
>> cPickle.loads(cPickle.dumps(lambda x:x))
TypeError: can't pickle function objects
```

What went wrong? Let's see the dispatch table of `cPickle`.

```
>> cPickle.Pickler.dispatch_table
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'dispatch_table'
```

The implementation of `pickle` and `cPickle` is different. `Importing` dill makes only Python version of `pickle` work. The disadvantage of using `pickle` instead of `cPickle` is that it can be as much as **1000 times** slower than cPickle.

I hope this clears all the doubts.

Comment: This answer should be accepted. It nicely explains the usability and limitations with the `dill` package in each python version. Well done!

Answer (score 34):

No, Python can't pickle lambda functions:

```
>>> import cPickle as pickle
>>> s = pickle.dumps(lambda x,y: x+y)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.py", line 70, in _reduce_ex
    raise TypeError, "can't pickle %s objects" % base.__name__
TypeError: can't pickle function objects
```

Not sure what you did that succeeded...

Comment: I don't know why this comment is down voted. pickle can't serialize lambdas only dill package can

Comment: Why can't python pickle lambdas?

Answer (score 2):

Even though it might be obvious I would like to add an other possible solution.
As you probably know lambda functions are just anonymous function declarations. If you don't have many lambdas that are used only once and it wouldn't add much noise to your code you could just name your lambda and pass the name of it (without the parentheses) like this:

```
import cPickle as pickle

def addition(x, y):
    return x+y


if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = pickle.dumps(addition)
    f = pickle.loads(s)
    assert f(3,4) == 7
```

The name also adds more semantic and you wouldn't need an additional dependency like Dill. But only do that if that outweighs the added noise of the additional function(s).

Answer (score 2):

what worked for me (windows 10, python 3.7) was to pass a function instead of a lambda function:

```
def merge(x):
    return Image.merge("RGB", x.split()[::-1])

transforms.Lambda(merge)
```

instead of:

```
transforms.Lambda(lambda x: Image.merge("RGB", x.split()[::-1]))
```

no dill or cPickel needed.

Answer (score 1):

Install dill

```
$ pip install dill
```

Touch a file

```
touch yeah.p
```

Now run this python3 script,

```
import dill

dill.dump(lambda x:x+1, open('yeah.p', 'wb'))
my_lambda = dill.load(open('yeah.p', 'rb'))
print(my_lambda(2))  # 3
```