# MultiProcessing in python3 not working

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

I am using multi processing in python3 for first time. Here is what I am trying to implement :

```
import concurrent
t = concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(4)
g = t.map(lambda x:10*x, range(10))
```

And it is throwing errors:

```
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 242, in _feed
    obj = ForkingPickler.dumps(obj)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.4.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 50, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function <lambda> at 0x102f03730>: attribute lookup <lambda> on __main__ failed
```

and hangs out every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function passed to `t.map` [needs to be picklable](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor). Anonymous functions (i.e. lambda functions) [are not picklable](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled) -- at least [not by default](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25348532/190597). To fix, define the function in the global namespace:

```
import concurrent.futures as CF
def func(x):
    return 10*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with CF.ProcessPoolExecutor(4) as t:
        g = t.map(func, range(10))
        print(list(g))
        # [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]
```