# TypeError: can't pickle function objects while writing generator

Tags: python, pickle

I already checked similar threads, my issue seems different.

I am trying t pickle object. I tried simple example on terminal which works. I have used same apprach in this code, which gives error. This is the same code which works fine on someone else system. I just replicated on my system.

Is it due to content I am trying to write in pickle?

full code - https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b0e84df9a05f165ea2dd

```
def train(self):
    global pos, neg, totals
    retrain = False

    # Load counts if they already exist.
    if not retrain and os.path.isfile(CDATA_FILE):
        pos, neg, totals = cPickle.load(open(CDATA_FILE))
        return

    limit = 12500
    for file in os.listdir("./aclImdb/train/pos")[:limit]:
        for word in set(self.negate_sequence(open("./aclImdb/train/pos/" + file).read())):
            print word

            pos[word] += 1
            neg['not_' + word] += 1
    for file in os.listdir("./aclImdb/train/neg")[:limit]:
        for word in set(self.negate_sequence(open("./aclImdb/train/neg/" + file).read())):
            neg[word] += 1
            pos['not_' + word] += 1

    self.prune_features()

    totals[0] = sum(pos.values())
    totals[1] = sum(neg.values())

    countdata = (pos, neg, totals)
    cPickle.dump(countdata, open(CDATA_FILE, 'w'))
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sentiment_worker.py", line 146, in <module>
    MyDict().gearman_worker.work()
  File "sentiment_worker.py", line 28, in __init__
    self.train()
  File "sentiment_worker.py", line 91, in train
    cPickle.dump(countdata, open(CDATA_FILE, 'w'))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.py", line 70, in _reduce_ex
    raise TypeError, "can't pickle %s objects" % base.__name__
TypeError: can't pickle function objects
```

Comment: Is it possible this code works/doesn't work on one OS but doesn't work/works on a different one?

Comment: @leongold: both are the same OS

Comment: The whole source is hard to understand with all that code operating on global variables and the class that simply doesn't make sense. Also pickle files contain _binary_ data and therefore must be opened in binary mode. Otherwise the data may not be readable on other operating systems. Regarding the exception: take a look at the structure you try to pickle, find the function object, find the place in the code where it gets into the data, and fix it.

Comment: @user3449212: Check this out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25348532/can-python-pickle-lambda-functions