# How to convert `lambda` object to `function` object for pickling in Python?

Tags: python, function, object, lambda, functools

I've been dealing with errors regarding `lambda` functions and their inability to be `pickled`.  I often use `lambda` functions on the fly as one time use functions and it vastly decreases my workflow productivity when I have to individually recreate simple lambda functions in functional form for use with pickling.

**Is there a way to convert a `lambda` and all of its arguments into a `function` object in `Python 3.6.1`?**

```
lambda_func = lambda x: x.split(" ")
def func(x):
    return x.split(" ")
input_string = "Darth Plagueis was a Dark Lord of the Sith"

# Function Version
func(input_string)
# ['Darth', 'Plagueis', 'was', 'a', 'Dark', 'Lord', 'of', 'the', 'Sith']
lambda_func(input_string)
# ['Darth', 'Plagueis', 'was', 'a', 'Dark', 'Lord', 'of', 'the', 'Sith']

def lambda2func(lambda_func):
    #...
    return func_version
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Python pickle lambda functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25348532/can-python-pickle-lambda-functions)

Comment: Check out the `dill` module - it extends pickling to handle various other types, including lambdas.

Comment: `lambda_func = lambda x: x.split(" ")` is already a misuse of `lambda`. Is that how you use it in your code? Can you show a working example of what you are trying to pickle?

Comment: I was giving an example of a lambda function as a toy example.  The end goal is for parallel mapping but the question is asking if a lambda object can be converted to a function object. I've seen a use case where dill can be imported as pickle which is pretty cool but gets confusing in the code since I used pickle and dill for different types of serialization.

Comment: Are you actually *naming* lambda functions in your code? I believe that was the issue `tdelaney` was talking about. There is almost never a good reason not to use a full function definition in place of a lambda. If your lambda is truely made "on the fly for one-time use" then why does it need to be pickled?

Comment: Also, `lambdas` *are* function objects. The problem is that they don't have a name, which is what `pickle` does. It doesn't actually serialize the code. For that, you have to use `dill`

Comment: I'm not actually naming lambda functions in my code.  They are done on the fly but I did it for easy readability instead of copying a block of confusing code to illustrate the point.  Is there a way to assign a name to a function in this case? Or is importing dill as pickle the only option?

Answer (score 3):

`pickle` does not save the code object, just its name. However, giving a function a name is not enough to make it pickleable, because `unpickle` deserializes it by importing the name. Naturally, this means it must be *importable* by the unpickling runtime. Functions `def`ed with names can still fail to pickle for this reason. So even if you could convert your lambdas to named functions, that still wouldn't work:

```
>>> import pickle
>>> def foo():
...   def bar():
...     pass
...   return bar
...
>>> pickle.dumps(foo())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'foo.<locals>.bar'
```

You say your reason for not using `dill` instead is

> I've seen a use case where dill can be imported as pickle which is pretty cool but gets confusing in the code since I used pickle and dill for different types of serialization.

But the `pickle` serialization format is *extensible* to any internal format you please —`json`, `gzip`, even `dill`. You can have your cake and eat it too!

Let's try it with `dill`, because that makes it easy:

```
import pickle
import dill
​
class DillPickle:
    def __init__(self, e):
        self.e = e
    def __getstate__(self):
        return dill.dumps(self.e)
    def __setstate__(self, state):
        self.e = dill.loads(state)
```

Pickle normally serializes the state of custom class instances by recursively pickling the object's `__dict__`. On unpickling, it can then make an uninitialized instance and update its `__dict__` with the saved values. If all of its contents are pickleable all the way down, this works. But if not, (as in the case of the lambdas) pickling would fail. But the `pickle` module provides an interface to override this behavior: `__getstate__()` for serializing the object's state, and `__setstate__()` for restoring it from that value. If the return value of `__getstate__()` is picklable (and `__setstate__()` is implemented), this works. In this case, we return the picklable bytestring returned by `dill.dumps()`.

Demonstration:

```
>>> pickle.dumps(DillPickle(lambda x, y: x+y))
b'\x80\x03c__main__\nDillPickle\nq\x00)\x81q\x01C\xe7\x80\x03cdill._dill\n_create_function\nq\x00(cdill._dill\n_load_type\nq\x01X\x08\x00\x00\x00CodeTypeq\x02\x85q\x03Rq\x04(K\x02K\x00K\x02K\x02KCC\x08|\x00|\x01\x17\x00S\x00q\x05N\x85q\x06)X\x01\x00\x00\x00xq\x07X\x01\x00\x00\x00yq\x08\x86q\tX\x1f\x00\x00\x00<ipython-input-18-48b9de2c6f55>q\nX\x08\x00\x00\x00<lambda>q\x0bK\x01C\x00q\x0c))tq\rRq\x0ec__builtin__\n__main__\nh\x0bNN}q\x0fNtq\x10Rq\x11.q\x02b.'
>>> pickle.loads(_).e('foo', 'bar')
'foobar'
```

Notice that we loaded it with `pickle`, not `dill`! And the lambda *does not have a name*. Of course, `dill` must be available to the runtime in order to unpickle, but so does the rest of the `DillPickle` class, just like for any custom type serialized with `pickle`. `dill` is now a mere implementation detail used internally by `DillPickle`. The interface is `pickle`.

You could even make it a callable, so you don't need to add the `.e` yourself.

```
class DillPickleCallable(DillPickle):
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.e(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: can you explain briefly __getstate__() and __setstate__()?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickling-class-instances

Comment: My point is that it would be helpful in your post to include a mention about what they do. (I've seen the doc on it myself ;) )