# How to fetch elements from a generator using Pool?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a generator that I want to listify.

`gen = requests.get(url, stream=True).iter_content(chunk_size=100)`

I want to listify this parallely.

`out = list(gen)` does it synchronously.

Running this:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
out = Pool(10).imap((lambda x: x), gen)
```

gives error:

```
    raise value
cPickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'function'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.function failed
```

Comment: Replace your `lambda` with an actual named function and it should work. Alternatively, `import dill`. [More info on lambda pickling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25348532/can-python-pickle-lambda-functions)

Comment: It did, but why doesn't lambda work?