# What is the best way to save a complex dictionary to file?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a dictionary that has tuple keys and numpy array values.  I tried saving it using h5 and pickle but I get error messages.  what is the best way to save this object to file?

```
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict
Q =defaultdict(lambda: np.zeros(2))
Q[(1,2,False)] = np.array([1,2])
Q[(1,3,True)] = np.array([3,4])

>>> Q
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x10c51ce18>, {(1, 2, False): array([1, 2]), (1, 3, True): array([3, 4])})
```

np.save traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-99-a071e1561501> in <module>()
----> 1 np.save('Q.npy', Q)

~/anaconda3_420/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py in save(file, arr, allow_pickle, fix_imports)
    509         arr = np.asanyarray(arr)
    510         format.write_array(fid, arr, allow_pickle=allow_pickle,
--> 511                            pickle_kwargs=pickle_kwargs)
    512     finally:
    513         if own_fid:

~/anaconda3_420/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/format.py in write_array(fp, array, version, allow_pickle, pickle_kwargs)
    584         if pickle_kwargs is None:
    585             pickle_kwargs = {}
--> 586         pickle.dump(array, fp, protocol=2, **pickle_kwargs)
    587     elif array.flags.f_contiguous and not array.flags.c_contiguous:
    588         if isfileobj(fp):

AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'mc_control_epsilon_greedy.<locals>.<lambda>'
```

Comment: what are the errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about saving it as a plain dictionary?  You don't need the `defaultdict` behavior during saving.

```
In [126]: from collections import defaultdict
In [127]: Q =defaultdict(lambda: np.zeros(2))
     ...: Q[(1,2,False)] = np.array([1,2])
     ...: Q[(1,3,True)] = np.array([3,4])
     ...: Q[(3,4,False)]
     ...: 
Out[127]: array([0., 0.])
In [128]: Q
Out[128]: 
defaultdict(<function __main__.<lambda>>,
            {(1, 2, False): array([1, 2]),
             (1, 3, True): array([3, 4]),
             (3, 4, False): array([0., 0.])})
```

We can pull it out of the `defaultdict` wrapping with:

```
In [130]: dict(Q)
Out[130]: 
{(1, 2, False): array([1, 2]),
 (1, 3, True): array([3, 4]),
 (3, 4, False): array([0., 0.])}
```

Then we can pickle it (I'm using `np.save` as a pickle shortcut)

```
In [131]: np.save('stack49963862', np.array(dict(Q)))
```

`load` gives an object array containing this dictionary:

```
In [132]: P = np.load('stack49963862.npy')
In [133]: P
Out[133]: 
array({(1, 2, False): array([1, 2]), (1, 3, True): array([3, 4]), (3, 4, False): array([0., 0.])},
      dtype=object)

In [138]: P.item()
Out[138]: 
{(1, 2, False): array([1, 2]),
 (1, 3, True): array([3, 4]),
 (3, 4, False): array([0., 0.])}
```

We can easily recreate the defaultdict with an update:

```
In [134]: Q1 =defaultdict(lambda: np.zeros(2))
In [139]: Q1.update(P.item())
In [140]: Q1
Out[140]: 
defaultdict(<function __main__.<lambda>>,
            {(1, 2, False): array([1, 2]),
             (1, 3, True): array([3, 4]),
             (3, 4, False): array([0., 0.])})
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problems using `pickle`

```
import pickle
import numpy as np

x = {(1,2,False): np.array([1,4]), (1,3,False): np.array([4,5])}

with open('filename.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(x, handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
with open('filename.pickle', 'rb') as handle:
    y = pickle.load(handle)

print x
print y
```

---

**After the edit:**

What you actually have is a `lambda`, and that cannot be pickled by default. You need to install `dill` and import it for it to work (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25353243/3512538))

This is how it should look like:

```
import pickle
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict
import dill # doesn't come with default anaconda. Install with "conda install dill"

x = defaultdict(lambda: np.zeros(2))
with open('filename.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(x, handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
with open('filename.pickle', 'rb') as handle:
    y = pickle.load(handle)

print x
print y
```

**Output:**

```
# no errors :-)
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x000000000CD0C898>, {})
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x0000000002614C88>, {})
```

---

***OP's solution:***
your edited solution still generated the same error for me but this works fine:

```
import pickle
import dill
dill_file = open("Q.pickle", "wb")
dill_file.write(dill.dumps(Q))
dill_file.close()
```

*On my machine (Win 8.1 64 bit, using Spyder), I had no errors when using simple `dill`.*

Comment: `---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-100-2776507a179b> in <module>()
      1 import pickle
      2 with open('fQ.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
----> 3     pickle.dump(Q, handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'mc_control_epsilon_greedy.<locals>.<lambda>'`

Comment: Is it possible you are actually trying to pickle another object and not the dictionary? (by your error massage, it seems that way). Please post your MCVE in the question's body

Comment: would it matter if it's a defaultdict object?  `defaultdict(lambda: np.zeros(2))`

Comment: It clearly does matter. Your code does not run, and mine does. Please post the whole thing

Comment: Sorry, I thought I was simplifying the post.  Obviously, not a good idea.  I posted the actual object the gave the error now.

Comment: That's fine. Next time read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and post questions accordingly :-)