# Parallelizing Pandas DataFrame function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

The task is to create a single function to

- parallelize the `pd.DataFrame.apply` function by splitting the rows into portions depending on the number of partitions requested by the users
- allow a user-specified function to be passed into the parallized apply function

E.g. given a text input, I have tried:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from nltk import word_tokenize

def apply_me(df_this):
    return df_this[0].astype(str).apply(word_tokenize)

def parallelize_apply(df, apply_me, num_partitions):
    df_split = np.array_split(df, num_partitions)
    pool = Pool(num_partitions)
    df = pd.concat(pool.map(apply_me, df_split))
    pool.close()
    pool.join
    return df

text = """Let's try something.
I have to go to sleep.
Today is June 18th and it is Muiriel's birthday!
Muiriel is 20 now.
The password is "Muiriel"."""

df = pd.DataFrame(text.split('\n'))

parallelize_apply(df, apply_me, 2)
```

[out]:

Out[8]:

```
0                         [Let, 's, try, something, .]
1                      [I, have, to, go, to, sleep, .]
2    [Today, is, June, 18th, and, it, is, Muiriel, ...
3                            [Muiriel, is, 20, now, .]
4              [The, password, is, ``, Muiriel, '', .]
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

My question is **is there's a way for me to put the `word_tokenize()` function into the `parallize_apply()` and not hard_code into the `apply_me()` function** ?

---

Simplifying the functions, I've tried:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from nltk import word_tokenize

def apply_me(df_this, func):
    return df_this[0].astype(str).apply(func)

def parallelize_apply(df, func, num_partitions):
    df_split = np.array_split(df, num_partitions)
    with Pool(num_partitions) as pool:
        _apply_me = partial(apply_me, func=func)
        df = pd.concat(pool.map(_apply_me, df_split))
        pool.join
    return df.tolist()

text = """Let's try something.
I have to go to sleep.
Today is June 18th and it is Muiriel's birthday!
Muiriel is 20 now.
The password is "Muiriel"."""

df = pd.DataFrame(text.split('\n'))

parallelize_apply(df, word_tokenize, 6)
```

It achieved the same output but there's still a need to have a middle-function `apply_me` for the `parallelize_apply` to work as desired. Is there a way to remove it?

Comment: What do you aim to achieve by eliminating `apply_me`? You're already passing `word_tokenize` directly to `parallelize_apply`.

Comment: I'm not sure why is there a need for `apply_me` to exist. When I replaced it with a lambda function inside `parallelize_apply`, multiprocessing isn't very happy about pooling lambda functions.

Comment: Oh, that's seems like `picke/cpickle` crap. You should use `dill` or, better, `dill` with `joblib` [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25348532/can-python-pickle-lambda-functions).

Comment: Is it passing serialized outputs across the Pool?! That's doesn't seem very secure (though not my concern of the project). Thanks for the suggestion! Let me try `joblib` =)

Comment: Yeah, this is Python: there's no real parallelism, just multiple interpreters in different address spaces. To cross them, you have to pass things through, somehow.

Comment: `apply()` is dead slow.  Parallelizing it will only get you a 2-10x speedup after you imposed a 1000x slowdown on yourself.  Don't do this at all.  For your given example, use `df.str.split()` instead--it is a vectorized operation that does more or less the same thing but lightning quick.  If you really can't do that, just use something like  `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor.map(word_tokenize, text)` before creating a Pandas structure.