# How to save LambdaLR scheduler in pytorch with lambda function?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

Running pytorch 0.4.1 with python 3.6 I encountered this problem:
I cannot `torch.save` my learning rate scheduler because python won't pickle a lambda function:

```
lambda1 = lambda epoch: epoch // 30
scheduler = LambdaLR(optimizer, lr_lambda=lambda1)
torch.save(scheduler.state_dict(), 'scheduler.pth.tar')
```

results with an error

> ```
> PicklingError: Can't pickle <function <lambda> at 0x7f7583fe92f0>:
> attribute lookup <lambda> on __main__ failed
> ```

How can I save my scheduler?

---

I know that using a proper function instead of a lambda function for `lambda1` can be saved, but I need a lambda function because I want to be able to control this function when it is defined (for instance I want to be able to change the fixed 30 in the denominator).
How can this be done and still allows me to save the scheduler?

Comment: You can use dill to save the pickle instead of `torch.save`. `lambda` function can't be pickled https://bugs.python.org/issue19272

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25348532/can-python-pickle-lambda-functions

Comment: @UmangGupta indeed using `dill` can solve the issue, but I'd rather stick to pytorch's save method

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If one wishes to stay with default behavior of `torch.save` and `torch.load`, the lambda function can be replaced with a class, for example:

```
class LRPolicy(object):
    def __init__(self, rate=30):
        self.rate = rate

    def __call__(self, epoch):
        return epoch // self.rate
```

The scheduler is now

```
scheduler = LambdaLR(optimizer, lr_lambda=LRPolicy(rate=30))
```

Now the scheduler can be `torch.save`ed and `torch.load` without alternating the pickling module.

Comment: You could also write a function that returns a function, eh?

Comment: @UmangGupta the returned function would then be a `local` of the function creating it - python won't `pickle` it. I tried.

Comment: This is hands down the correct answer. Anybody can explain why this one works?

Comment: @FurkanKüçük, because when it gets loaded it can find a definition of that class. It will fail to load if this class has not been imported, say, in another script where you just load the dict, but not the class.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but this is not a good permanent solution. As @stason mentioned, if the file defining the `LRPolicy` class is renamed, moved or deleted, `torch.load` will fail with an `AttributeError `, making the checkpoint unusable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `dill` as the pickle module instead of default pickle.

```
import dill
torch.save(scheduler.state_dict(), 'scheduler.pth.tar', pickle_module=dill)
```

and to load

```
import dill
object = torch.load('scheduler.pth.tar', pickle_module=dill)
```

See [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html?highlight=save#torch.save) of save for more options.

Comment: Could you include a sentence what differentiates `dill` from `pickle` in this case? Also, the docs link seems broken.