# Save (pickle) Scipy KDE

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scipy

How can I pickle or save a scipy kde for later use?

```
import scipy.stats as scs
from sklearn.externals import joblib

kde = scs.gaussian_kde(data, bw_method=.15)
joblib.dump(kde, 'test.pkl')
```

I tried above and received this error:

```
PicklingError: Can't pickle <function gaussian_kde.set_bandwidth.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x1a5b6fb7b8>: it's not found as scipy.stats.kde.gaussian_kde.set_bandwidth.<locals>.<lambda>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like joblib is having trouble with the [`set_bandwith`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/14142ff70d84a6ce74044a27919c850e893648f7/scipy/stats/kde.py#L439-L499) method, my guess is because of the `lambda` function in the method -- [pickling lambdas has been discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25348532/can-python-pickle-lambda-functions).

```python
with open('test.pkl', 'wb') as fo:  
    joblib.dump(lambda x,y: x+y, fo)

PicklingError: Can't pickle <function <lambda> at 0x7ff89495d598>: it's not found as __main__.<lambda>
```

[cloudpickle](https://github.com/cloudpipe/cloudpickle) and [dill](https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill) both work as far as I can tell:

```python
import cloudpickle
import dill

with open('test.cp.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    cloudpickle.dump(kde, f)  

with open('test.dill.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    dill.dump(kde, f)

with open('test.cp.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    kde_cp = cloudpickle.load(f)

with open('test.dill.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    kde_dill = dill.load(f)
```

Inspect some of the data:

```python
import numpy as np

print(np.array_equal(kde.dataset, kde_cp.dataset))
True
print(np.array_equal(kde.dataset, kde_dill.dataset))
True
print(np.array_equal(kde_cp.dataset, kde_dill.dataset))
True

kde.pdf(10) == kde_cp.pdf(10) == kde_dill.pdf(10)
array([ True])
```