# How to parallelize a function that returns a lambda

Tags: python, lambda, python-multithreading

I have a function that generates a lambda and places it into a dictionary, along these lines:

```py
class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        self.functions = {}

    def create_function(self, key):
        (code that sets up parameters)
        func = scipy.interpolate.interp2d(x, y, z)     # returns a function for interpolation
        self.functions[key] = lambda a, b: func(b, a)  # axes need to be switched
```

In a different part of the class, this function is called in a loop that I'd like to parallelize, as it takes ~30 seconds to run in serial. I've tried using `multiprocessing`'s `Pool`, but that can't write to the dictionary. I've also tried modifying the function to return the lambda in a couple ways, but it can't return a lambda, saying `AttributeError("Can't pickle local object '(class).(function).<locals>.<lambda>'")`.

The below code segments would be in a method of `Example`, and are approximately what I tried.

```py
pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
keys = []  # list of keys it needs to operate on
(code to set up keys)

# Doesn't work, won't write to dictionary (Effectively does nothing but take up time)
pool.map(self.create_function, keys)

# Doesn't work, can't return lambda (AttributeError)
new_dict = dict(pool.map(self.create_function, keys))
self.functions.update(new_dict)
```

Is there a way to parallelize this?

EDIT:
I was able to solve the problem as relevant to my project by separating the `(code that sets up parameters)` part and paralellizing that instead, but the question is still relevant - how can a function that returns a lambda be parallelized?

Comment: Can you show where `method_getting_function()` is defined and a minimal version of what it does? There's not quite enough here to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @MatthiasFripp I've updated it, it's scipy's `interp2d`.

Comment: Thanks. I also should have asked, what is `self` here? Is your second block of code running inside some method of `Example`? It would help if you give a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @MatthiasFripp I've edited it again, hopefully this should help. Both code segments would be in methods of  `Example`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can Python pickle lambda functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25348532/can-python-pickle-lambda-functions)

Comment: Yes, it does. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25348532/can-python-pickle-lambda-functions) linked by @quamrana, using a package such as `dill` allows lambdas and other things to be pickled/serialized, and therefore returned in parallel.