# How to transform a lambda function into a pickle-able function

Tags: python, pickle, dill

One can use the wonderful `dill` package to pickle lambda functions (amongst others). [See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25353243/5758423). Here though, I'd like to dynamically transform lambda functions into object that are functionally equivalent, but are builtin-picklable. (I can give more context if necessary.)

I came up with the following, but my way of extracting code from a lambda function is fragile, and reconstructing the function using `eval` is scary (but should it be, given one should only unpickle data one trusts anyway -- see [pickle module's warning](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)).

```py
import inspect, pickle

# TODO: Fragile. Make more robust.
def lambda_code(lambda_func):
    func_str = str(inspect.getsourcelines(lambda_func)[0])
    return func_str.strip("['\\n']").split(" = ")[1]

class PicklableLambda:
    def __init__(self, lambda_func):
        self.func = lambda_func
        self.__signature__ = inspect.signature(self.func)

    def __getstate__(self):
        return lambda_code(self.func)
    
    def __setstate__(self, func_code):
        func = eval(func_code)  # scary?
        self.__init__(func)
    
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.func(*args, **kwargs)

f = lambda x, y=0: x + y
ff = PicklableLambda(f)
fff = pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(ff))

assert fff(2, 3) == ff(2, 3) == f(2, 3)
```

Comment: This seem to have been address [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25348532/can-python-pickle-lambda-functions)

Comment: @vic, that's what I thought too (thus the first few lines of my post) but it doesn't solve my problem of "making an object that IS picklable by BUILTIN pickle".