# "can't pickle local object" in multiprocessing

Tags: python, debugging, multiprocessing, fork, pickle

I met the "can't pickle local object" problem. The warning message was like:

```
  File "/root/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'Embedding.__init__.<locals>.<lambda>'
```

And the code is as followed:

```
class ForkingPickler(pickle.Pickler):
    '''Pickler subclass used by multiprocessing.'''
    _extra_reducers = {}
    _copyreg_dispatch_table = copyreg.dispatch_table

    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
        self.dispatch_table = self._copyreg_dispatch_table.copy()
        self.dispatch_table.update(self._extra_reducers)

    @classmethod
    def register(cls, type, reduce):
        '''Register a reduce function for a type.'''
        cls._extra_reducers[type] = reduce

    @classmethod
    def dumps(cls, obj, protocol=None):
        buf = io.BytesIO()
        cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
        return buf.getbuffer()

    loads = pickle.loads

register = ForkingPickler.register

def dump(obj, file, protocol=None):
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
```

Can anyone tell me why would it be and how to solve the problem?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: It appears that the object in question is a lambda function, which can't be pickled. You can use the `dill` library for pickling, which supports pickling lambda functions, but you can also just either replace the lambda function with a regular function, or define the lambda function at the global (module) level so it doesn't have to be pickled. For lots more info (this is a deep topic) see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25348532/can-python-pickle-lambda-functions